# Один QVector для разных типов объектов

Tags: c++, qt

Возник такой вопрос: у меня есть главный класс Figures, от которого я унаследовал Circle,Square,Triangle и т.д. Теперь хочу создать QVector для хранения всех объектов, которые наследовал от Figures.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно объявить QVector и использовать его(обращение к конкретному элементу)? И корректно ли будет так делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно объявить вектор указателей на Figures, записывая в эти указатели адреса объектов конкретных фигур:

```
QVector<Figures*> figures;
```

Добавить элемент при помощи метода [push_back](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#push_back-1), например:

```
figures.push_back(new Circle(params));
figures.push_back(new Triangle(params));
figures.push_back(new Square(params));
```

Использовать это можно примерно так:

```
for(int i = 0; i < figures.size(); i++)
    figures[i]->move(10, 10);            // если метод move объявлен в Figures
```

Следует отметить, что в этом случае вы сможете использовать только те методы, о которых "знает" класс `Figures` (реализованные в нем или виртуальные). Чтобы использовать методы конкретной фигуры, например радиус для окружности, вам нужно будет сделать преобразование типа указателя из `Figures*` в `Circle*`.